# ros2 rclpy list parameters from node

Tags: ros, ros2, parameters, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an easy way to list parameters from an rclpy Node ??
I can 'manually' set up a service client and do the `list_parameters` call but it feels like this should be abstracted,

Current solution,

```
class Dummy(Node):
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__('dummy', allow_undeclared_parameters=True,
                       automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides=True)
  
      service_name = self.get_name() + '/list_parameters'
      client = self.create_client(ListParameters, service_name)

      while not client.service_is_ready():
          time.sleep(0.1)
          
      request = ListParameters.Request()
      future = client.call_async(request)
  
      # wait for response
      rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)
  
      if future.result is not None:
          response = future.result()
          for name in sorted(response.result.names):
              print('  {name}'.format_map(locals()))
```

Desired,

```
class Dummy(Node):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__('dummy', allow_undeclared_parameters=True,
                           automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides=True)
          param_list = self.list_parameters()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327280/ros2-rclpy-list-parameters-from-node/) by [artivis](https://answers.ros.org/users/11816/artivis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2019-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Artivis,

The service call is the solution if you need to list the parameters of *another* node.

If you want to do something with the parameters within the node (`Dummy` in your case), just use the "private" member `self._parameters`, which is a map with the parameter names as keys and Parameter objects as values: https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/0.7.4/rclpy/rclpy/node.py#L133.

If you just want a list:

```
class Dummy(Node):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__('dummy', allow_undeclared_parameters=True,
                           automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides=True)
          param_list = [parameter for parameter in self._parameters.values()]
```

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2019-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [artivis](https://answers.ros.org/users/11816/artivis/) on 2019-07-04**:
Hi, thanks for the tip !

Is this `self._parameters` member the place were the parameters live ? The actual concern being to know whether this member is up-to-date at launch time given that `allow_undeclared_parameters=True` and `automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides=True` ?  A quick test suggests that yes.

Notice that in my particular example the actual code would be
`sorted(list(self._parameters.keys()))`

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2019-07-04**:
Yw! Yes, that's where parameters actually live. Getting them after calling `super().__init__` should give you the up-to-date dictionary.
And yes, if you just want a sorted list of names that line should be just fine.

**Comment by [artivis](https://answers.ros.org/users/11816/artivis/) on 2019-07-04**:
Thanks for the precision ! Cheers.